# Find checkbox with a class of a variable JQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, checkbox

I need to find a checkbox with a class that is contained within the variable `preciseClass`.

My attempt below is not working. Where am I going wrong?

```
var preciseClass = $('#box2').attr('class');


$('#box1').find('li input:checkbox.' + preciseClass).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: space is missing after checkbox it should be checkbox .'

Comment: Use the javascript console in Firefox or Chrome. You can execute statements to verify that your selectors are correct.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure unless the input is what he's after.  And considering input nodes don't usually have children, I'm guessing this is unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that the node has multiple classes in which case you might be able to use something like this:

```
var preciseClass = $('#box2').attr('class').split(" ").join(".");

$('#box1').find('li input:checkbox.' + preciseClass).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: @CecilTheodore could it be that you are using `#box2` but looking under `#box1`?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, today has been a BAD day! thanks for your help youve helped me work it out.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the value of preciseClass; if you have multiple class applied to box2 element : it will not work as you expect.

can you make an alert or a console.log of the value?
http://jsfiddle.net/bxeys/

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a space after :checkbox

```
$('#box1').find('li input:checkbox .' + preciseClass).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: no... the `. classname` will cause it to look for any `classname` nodes, which probably don't exist.